# is there a way to select all cells below in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to select ALL the cells below the cursor (or above) in Jupyter Notebook with one command (not doing it one-by-one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible in Jupyter Notebook, but it is possible in JupyterLab using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, so by extension you can use it in [RetroLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/retrolab) which is a Jupyter Notebook layout recreation using JupyterLab components.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can <kbd>Select</kbd> the given cell, then scroll to the bottom of your notebook and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Select</kbd> the last cell. This will select all cells in between.